# Which item teleports you randomly on taking damage?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

I had a fine Lazarus run going yesterday, until Satan.

Then some item decided to ruin my day and I'm trying to figure out which item it was.
Apparently its effect would be that whenever one gets hit there would be a chance to get teleported to a seemingly random room, regardless of your HP.

Now I don't know anymore which items exactly I had, but I did check them during the run and most of them were "old" items anyway.
My trinkets were Petrified Poop and Left Hand, I doubt those played a role.

So, which item/mechanic could have caused that?

Comment: Looks like side effect of cursed eye. Had the same thing today, ruined an awesome run.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unless it was the Cursed Eye, which lets you do charged shots, I don't think it's an item at all. I just started a challenge run, and the only item I've picked up is the aforementioned Cursed Eye. But every time I take a single hit from the first boss, I'm immediately teleported out of the fight into another random room. It's making fighting the thing impossible.

So, it's either a side-effect of the Cursed Eye... Or it's a bug. My money's on the latter.

Comment: That's gotta be it, then. Thanks! According to the wiki, you only get teleported when charging (and getting hit). Considering it's "cursed charge shots", this might even be WAD.

Comment: It's definitely that item, the wikia states that "there is a chance of being warped out of the room upon taking damage". Damn side effect.

Answer (score 4):

http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Cursed_Eye

Cursed Eye
Effect
Grants charged tears that can be fired in a tight burst of four.
**Getting hit while charging will *teleport* Isaac into another room.**

Answer (score -1):

It is the cursed eye, I can confirm it. I have also just made a run with that item and as soon as I took red heart damage I got tp'd away every time.

Answer (score -1):

It could also be Guppy's Tail, if you pick it up; it says cursed in the description.

Comment: Guppy's Tail changes drop chances after clearing rooms. No teleportation happening there.